# How can I get started to write a Smart Card MiniDriver

Tags: smartcard

I'm familiar with smart card CSP and MiniDriver API's and Functionality, but In fact I dont know how to strat!
I need to have a roadmap about the steps that I should take to develop a MiniDriver dll.
Would you please help me.

Comment: That question is too vague for this forum, in case you were wondering why nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

1. get the smart card APDU reference
2. check how the smart card will fit in the minidriver functionnalities
   (read only smart card, how the unique id will be generated, will you allow to store files, ...)
3. Implement the minidriver
4. test it using cmck.exe (test used for digital signature)
5. build an msi (check out wix with the driver installer)
6. sign it

Answer (score 0):

hire someone who have experience about developing minidrivers would be my best answer because the task is far from beeing easy and there are but very few documentation about the subject, no books , no tutorials, no nothing. So unless you have a good experience dealing with the minidrivers already written -AND- communicating with the few people who wrote one already ( usually found in gemalto , oberthur or such companies ) -AND- beeing very curious -AND- be very patient ,etc .. writing a minidriver from scratch and alone will be a very hard task.